# Different views for same action in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile-website

I'm developing a Mobile web using ASP.NET MVC3. I need to change my views to be best fits according to different screen resolution available on difference sized devices.

Lets take an example,

Here I have an Action call SalesHistory. and view call SalesHistory.cshtml
I have decided to create 4 views ( **as sames as in native application development** ) to arrange content according to different screen resolutions available on different devices. 
So I need to have,

```
SalesHistory_xhdpi.cshtml
SalesHistory_hdpi.cshtml
SalesHistory_mdpi.cshtml
SalesHistory_ldpi.cshtml
```

Now I need to add the post fix ( _xhdpi/_hdpi/_mdpi or ldpi ) to the viewfile name just after the methods is invoked and before it looks the cshtml file in the file system. Here I have the logic to decide the post-pix.

How do I alter the view file name ?

Comment: MVC4 will allow it natively, chek this: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/exploring-aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Comment: yea.. but no chance to move to mvc4. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the changes can not be done with simple CSS queries and you absolutely must have different view files, you can do that with code such as:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("ldpi") {//condition to detect resolution)});
```

Take a look at this website for a great started especially the section on providing separate views by mobile type: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreateAGreatMobileExperienceForYourWebsiteTodayPlease.aspx